# Do Setters have to have an argument

Tags: objective-c

I have written a setter that is not working as expected. I am reading in statistics from a file and populating the properties of my SVTeam object with these stats. However some of the properties need to be calculated (as they are not supplied in the files). One of these properties holds the home winning percentage for a given team. I do not need to supply an argument for the setter. Two questions:

1. Since I'm NOT supplying an argument in my setter is it still truly a setter in an objective-c sense?
2. Even it if is not a true setter why does the code below still leave the properties as `null`?

SVTeam.h

```
@interface SVTeam : NSObject
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSNumber *homePercentage;
...
...
```

SVTeam.m

```
#import "SVTeam.h"
@implementation SVTeam
@synthesize homePercentage = _homePercentage;
...
...

-(void) setHomePercentage
{
    float wins = [_homeWins floatValue];
    float losses = [_homeLosses floatValue];
    float ties = [_homeTies floatValue];
    float winPercentage = wins / (wins+losses+ties);
    self.homePercentage = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:winPercentage];
}
```

Comment: How is the set getting called? `self.homePercentage` calls the setter and you are passing it a value. `setHomePercentage` isn't the setter for `homePercentage` property. The `@synthesize` (You don't need as does automatically now) generates the getters and setters for you so your method `setHomePercentage` doesn't override the generated one. To call this one from another class you need to add `- (void)setHomePercentage;` to your `.h` file.

Comment: I did not have the method declared in my .h file. Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 7):

Since homePercentage is a calculated value based on other properties you could make it a readonly property and you would have your calculation logic in the getter instead. If you leave it as a setter then your consumers would have to make sure to call the setter first and call the getter to retrieve the value.

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSNumber *homePercentage;
```

And your getter definition would be

```
- (NSNumber *)homePercentage
{
  ...
  return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:winPercentage];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Garfield81's answer:

If you want to override the setter synthesized by clang for you `homePercentage` property, you need to implement `-(void)setHomePercentage:(NSNumber *)homePercentage;` in your class.
[Apple documentation on properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/DeclaredProperty.html).

To answer your two questions:

> 1) since I'm NOT supplying an argument in my setter is it still truly a setter in an objective-c sense?

No. The synthesized setters takes an unique argument of the same type of the propery and are named `set<CapitalizedPropertyName>`. What you did is declare a new method.

> 2) even it if is not a true setter why does the code below still leave the properties as null

There is not apparent reason for `homePercentage` to stay `nil` (not `null`) from the code you provided. Are you sure your custom method gets called? (remember that when using the dot notation (`self.homePercentage`), this is `-(void)setHomePercentage:(NSNumber *)homePercentage;` which is called, not your `-(void)setHomePercentage;`).

Note also that you don't need to add `@synthesize homePercentage = _homePercentage;` [unless you override both the getter and the setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918388/why-do-i-need-to-write-synthesize-when-i-provide-getter-and-setter).

Comment: @Garfield81 Putting the calculation logic in the getter makes sense (wish I'd thought of that).  Guillaume, thank you for your for explanation. I had looked but didn't find the specific answer I was looking for.